# replaceNode method does not assign parentNode property?

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm trying to remove all event handlers from an input element in a DOM document .
The only way I know how to do this is to clone the element and call replaceChild method of the node parent to replace it.However neither of these functions copies the parentNode property of the original node. This is in Chrome.
Is this the right behavior? Or maybe I'm doing something wrong? Is there a way to clone a node preserving the parent? Ultimately, is there a  better way to remove all event handlers from an element?
Here is the code:

```
var parent = originalNode.parentNode;
var newNode= originalNode.cloneNode(true);  
parent.replaceChild(newNode, originalNode);
```

after the operation the parentNode property of newNode is null
Any ideas?
Thanks 
Andy

Comment: In which browser? Works fine in everything I've tested (as expected).

Comment: Chrome. Forgot to mention, the code executes from a browser extension.

Comment: User error. replaceNode method correctly copies the parentNode property. I was looking at the wrong variable in the debugger